# How can I set the newline type used by strings in a Resources file?

Tags: .net, resources, newline, embedded-resource

I have a Resources file in my project with a large number of multi-line strings defined in the string table. I can make these string multiline by hitting `Shift+Enter` when entering the string into the editor (or by copying and pasting a string with carriage returns from another editor).

My problem is that when I access these strings using the reference `Resources.StringName,` the resulting string uses the Windows newline (`\r\n`), when what I need is Unix newlines (`\n`).

I could do a `string.Replace()` on these values every time I access them, but that seems really inefficient. Alternatively, I could create a static class of constant strings instead of using a Resources file, and this is probably what I will do if there is not solution to my problem.

Ideally, what I would like to do is change a setting on the Resources file to set how the newline characters will be returned, rather like changing the `CultureInfo`. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

In the resource file, you can use '
' tag and while using the resource you need too get these value inside @Html.Raw() function like:

@Html.Raw(Resources..Message);

**OR**

```
You can use string.Replace() function like this:
```

```
string msg=Resources.<your_file_name>.Message;
string formatedMsg= msg.Replace("\\n","<br>");
```

Even if you want to define some CSS class in Resources so by using @Html.Raw() you can apply.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood my question. It sounds like you think this is a web application, and I am looking to encode carriage returns as their HTML counterpart tags. This is incorrect. First off, this has nothing to do with HTML, it is a general .Net question. Secondly, I want to get /n rather than /r/n. Finally, I already mentioned the string.Replace() possibility, so it is not at all helpful to suggest it.